# Passing More than 9 parameters through dynamicCall() in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, com

I am completely new to Qt and I am just trying to call my COM (build in VS2017) functionality from Qt through dynamicCall(). Though i am able to call most of my functionalities but stuck in a function which is caring  more than 9 parameters.

I have done like:

```
ui->axwidget-> dynamicCall("int&,QVariant,QVariant,int,int,int,double,int,Qstring,Qstring",par1,par2,....,par10);
```

i got error:

> no matching member function for call to "dynamicCall".
> note: Candidate function not viable: requires at most 9 arguments but 11 were provided.

Comment: I never used Qt but looks like 8 is the maximum (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#dynamicCall). I've had similar issues with other libraries and usually you can put all variables in a struct first. Looks like Qt also supports this : https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22952-SOLVED-QVariant-and-user-structures.

Comment: Another solution, besides that mentioned by @PepijnKramer, seems to be using an overloaded member function, `QVariant  dynamicCall(const char *function, QList<QVariant> &vars)`